# Supersampling AA with PyOpenGL and GLFW

Tags: opengl, glfw, antialiasing, pyopengl

I am developing a application with `OpenGL`+`GLFW` and Linux as a target platform.

The default rasterizing has VERY strong aliasing. I have implemented `FXAA` on top of my pipeline and I still got pretty strong aliasing. Especially when there's some kind of animation or movement, the edges of meshes are flickering. This literally renders the whole project useless.

So, I thought I would also add a supersampling and I have been trying to implement it for two weeks already and still can't make it work. I start to think it's not possible with the combination `PyOpenGL`+`GLFW`+`Ubuntu18.04`.

So, the question is, can I do a supersampling by hand (without OpenGL extentions)? At the end of my (deferred) rendering pipeline I save all the data from different passes to the hard drive, so I thought I would do something like this:

1. Render the image with `2x`/`3x` resolution to the texture.
2. Save the texturebuffer to the array.
3. Get the average pixel's value from each `2x2`/`3x3`/`4x4` block
   of this array.
4. Save it to the hard drive.

Obviously, it's gonna be slower than mulstisampling with OpenGL extention and require more memory, but I don't need high fps and I have a pretty small resolution (like `480x640` or similar) so it might work out.

Do you guys have any thoughts about it? I would be glad to any advice.

Comment: Use 2x resolution and texture filter `GL_LINEAR` when downsampling. Or 4x resolution and do the downsampling in 2 steps. See [`glBlitFramebuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml).

Comment: @Rabbid76 Great, thank you. I knew about `glBlitFramebuffer` but didn't know it can be used for downsampling. I'll try it out.

Comment: "*without OpenGL extentions*" What exactly does that mean in this day and age?